# How To use ExecuteSqlCommandAsync

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asynchronous, async-await

I've been trying to figure out `ExecuteSqlCommandAsync`, which I haven't been able to find any good documentation on.

```
if (OldMarketRightsIDs.Count > 0)
{
    //This is where I want to have the task Begin        
    TaskReturn = Data.MK3Model.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("DELETE FROM TitleMarketRights WHERE ID in (" + string.Join(", ", OldMarketRightsIDs) + ")");
}

//This is the Code I want To execute in between
var NewMarketRights = MarketRights.Select(m => new
{
    Key = m.Key,
    Value = m.Value.Except(CurrentMarketRights[m.Key].Select(c => c.FK_ProductRight).ToList())
}).ToList();

foreach (var mr in NewMarketRights)
{
    foreach (var ProdID in mr.Value)
    {
        Data.MK3Model.TitleMarketRights.Add(new TitleMarketRight { FK_MarketID = (mr.Key == 0) ? null : (int?)mr.Key, FK_TitleID = ID, FK_ProductRight = ProdID });
    }
}

//This is where I want to wait until the task is complete before continuing
var i = await TaskReturn;
```

This Example doesn't compile, it gets an error await operator can only be used with an async Method.  Any Ideas on how to get this working

Comment: You need to use await on the `ExecuteSqlCommandAsync`, the state machine will then take a snapshot of where it is in the code and leave till the call comes back. When the operation has finished executing, then the code will continue.

Comment: To be able to `await` your method should have the `async` keyword, like: `public async Task DoThings(){}`

Comment: You probably want to read up on how to use [`async`/`await`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443). Your question is not specific to Entity Framework or `ExecuteSqlCommandAsync` in particular.

Comment: You realize that the operation completes only after you `await` the returned task? All the code before it would run during the asynchronous operation.

Comment: Thats fine I want to add the new titles to The context but I don't call save changes until afterwards

Comment: This looks like a SQL Injection Attack waiting to happen. You shouldn't use string concatenation for your WHERE clause.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code is fine. It just needs to be inside an `async` method:

```
public async Task FooAsync()
{
    if (OldMarketRightsIDs.Count > 0)
    {
        TaskReturn = Data.MK3Model.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("DELETE FROM TitleMarketRights WHERE ID in (" + string.Join(", ", OldMarketRightsIDs) + ")");
    }

    var NewMarketRights = MarketRights.Select(m => new
    {
        Key = m.Key,
        Value = m.Value.Except(CurrentMarketRights[m.Key].Select(c => c.FK_ProductRight).ToList())
    }).ToList();

    foreach (var mr in NewMarketRights)
    {
        foreach (var ProdID in mr.Value)
        {
            Data.MK3Model.TitleMarketRights.Add(new TitleMarketRight { FK_MarketID = (mr.Key == 0) ? null : (int?)mr.Key, FK_TitleID = ID, FK_ProductRight = ProdID });
        }
    }

    var i = await TaskReturn;
}
```

That's what allows you to use `await`. Behind the scenes a state machine is built that handles the asynchronous nature of you method. The method needs to have the `async` keyword and return a `Task` or `Task<T>` if you have a return value.

If you would want to have it as a lambda expression then:

```
Func<Task> fooAsync = async () =>
{
    if (OldMarketRightsIDs.Count > 0)
    {
        TaskReturn = Data.MK3Model.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("DELETE FROM TitleMarketRights WHERE ID in (" + string.Join(", ", OldMarketRightsIDs) + ")");
    }

    var NewMarketRights = MarketRights.Select(m => new
    {
        Key = m.Key,
        Value = m.Value.Except(CurrentMarketRights[m.Key].Select(c => c.FK_ProductRight).ToList())
    }).ToList();

    foreach (var mr in NewMarketRights)
    {
        foreach (var ProdID in mr.Value)
        {
            Data.MK3Model.TitleMarketRights.Add(new TitleMarketRight { FK_MarketID = (mr.Key == 0) ? null : (int?)mr.Key, FK_TitleID = ID, FK_ProductRight = ProdID });
        }
    }

    var i = await TaskReturn;
};

var task = fooAsync();
```

Comment: Do you know how I can write this as a lambda?

Comment: This makes sense I'm going to try it out real quick

Comment: just wonder is this how I globally Declare a temp TaskReturn incase there is not an async call `Task<int> TaskReturn = new Task<int> ( new Func<int>(() => 0));`

Comment: @Space No. It would be better simply checking whether `task != null` before awaiting. But you can use `task = Task.FromResult(0)` to create a completed task as well...

Comment: I get a use of unassigned variable even if I check for null but the FromResult(0) works thanks

Comment: @Space you need to set `null` explicitly at first `Task<int> task = null;`

Answer (score -3):

You should just do this:

```
if (OldMarketRightsIDs.Count > 0)
{        
    await Data.MK3Model.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("DELETE FROM TitleMarketRights WHERE ID in (" + string.Join(", ", OldMarketRightsIDs) + ")");
}

//This code won't execute till the await has finished
var NewMarketRights = MarketRights.Select(m => new
{
    Key = m.Key,
    Value = m.Value.Except(CurrentMarketRights[m.Key].Select(c => c.FK_ProductRight).ToList())
}).ToList();

foreach (var mr in NewMarketRights)
{
    foreach (var ProdID in mr.Value)
    {
        Data.MK3Model.TitleMarketRights.Add(new TitleMarketRight { FK_MarketID = (mr.Key == 0) ? null : (int?)mr.Key, FK_TitleID = ID, FK_ProductRight = ProdID });
    }
}
```

When the await is hit, the state machine will take a snapshot and while the `Async` function is firing off, the process is free to do other things. But the code will not continue in this block until the `Async` function has finished firing. When it has, the state machine will comeback with the point at which to continue firing, aka that last `if` brace.

`await` just allows the process to do other things whilst this `Async` function is fired.

Also remember to have the surrounding function include the `async` keyword:

```
public async void DoSomething()
{

}
```

So the above will not "fire and forget" aka, just start and work in the background. In order to achieve that, I believe you call `Data.MK3Model.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync().Start()` to make it start. [MSDN Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: The OP specifically wants to run other things before awaiting. Also, don't use `async void` outside of event handlers.

Comment: No he didn't his comment in his code says, "//This is the Code I want To execute in between" which basically means during! Which is not how the await works

Comment: Nope, according to Jon Skeet, and Pluralsight, `await` willget the state machine to take a snapshot.... read my answer!

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from executing code between when the task starts and when you `await` it. If that's what OP wants to do, that's a different issue.

Comment: Where Does It Execute the code? is this the same as sync because nothing is happening between?

Comment: It won't start till it is called, or `await`ed, in this case, it won't start till the last line. So it isn't actually being run between.

Comment: @CallumLinington That is **completely false**.

Comment: @CallumLinington: I don't think I have ever claimed that using await will "take a snapshot". (It remembers where it's at, but that's not the same as taking a snapshot, which suggests making a copy of other state. The state is simply *in* the state machine.) And no, this code will *not* do as the OP wants, which is specifically to execute the middle bit of the code *without* waiting for the SQL command to complete.

Comment: @Space: Someone mentioned the post on Twitter, including my Twitter handle. But i3arnon's code was already fine :)

Comment: @JonSkeet no you didn't refer to it as a snap shot, that is my own twist that helps me explain, and I definately didn't quote you word for word, I took what I understood from you and just put it into my own words. I meant what you said, as in it just is in the state machine, rather then making copies. Yes and I agree with you, it won't do that I will update my answer.

Comment: @i3arnon I'm pretty sure its not false, when ever I execute a Task with `await` and have a break point immediately after, that break point will not be hit until the async code has finished.

Comment: @CallumLinington You don't execute a task with `await`. `await` logically just registers all the code after the `await` as a continuation. No code after the `await` would run until the task completed (successfully or not) but you can start the task before by calling the `async` method and getting back a task, do other things in the meantime and `await` only when you need to. The `async` operation doesn't wait for you to `await` the task before it starts running.

Comment: @i3arnon that is what I've been saying, apart from taking a reference for the `Task`. And in this situation there is no point in the OP `await`ing the `async` operation....

Comment: @CallumLinington I don't know what that sentence mean.